# Majuscule après un point d'interrogation ou pas ?

Tags: ponctuation, majuscules

Entre ces deux phrase quelle est la plus juste ? (ou sinon une autre proposition ?)

Ce que l'on cherche à savoir est : **q**ui consomme ? **q**uand ? **e**t combien ?

Ce que l'on cherche à savoir est : **Q**ui consomme ? **Q**uand ? **E**t combien ?

Aussi, y a-t-il lieu de mettre les deux points ou pas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un point d'interrogation est suivi d'une majuscule quand il termine une phrase et d'une minuscule quand la même phrase continue. Il a alors valeur de virgule.

Dans l'exemple donné, la forme correcte est :

> … est: qui consomme ? quand ? et combien ?

mais on aurait pu aussi écrire :

> … est: qui consomme, quand[,] et combien ?

Comment: dans ta deuxième phrase le [,] veut dire que la virgule est optionnelle ?

Comment: Oui, normalement on ne met pas de virgule avant le dernier terme d'une énumération mais ici la virgule peut se justifier pour marquer la pause.